# PHP 8.2 and PHPMailer doesn't send email to mailtrap sandbox

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have MacBook M1 and I installed php8.2 and httpd with brew.

I set up the Mailtrap SMTP sandbox and I tested sending email with the given curl request, which works.

So how my sendmail.php code looks like is:

```
<?php

require_once('phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');
require_once('phpmailer/class.smtp.php');

$mail = new PHPMailer();


$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output
$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'sandbox.smtp.mailtrap.io';                  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
// $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'e58e3babe7d651';    // SMTP username
$mail->Password = '9b******345c';                         // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 25;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$message = "";
$status = "false";

if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) {
    if( $_POST['form_name'] != '' AND $_POST['form_email'] != '' AND $_POST['form_subject'] != '' ) {

        $name = $_POST['form_name'];
        $email = $_POST['form_email'];
        $subject = $_POST['form_subject'];
        $phone = $_POST['form_phone'];
        $message = $_POST['form_message'];

        $subject = isset($subject) ? $subject : 'New Message | Contact Form';

        $botcheck = $_POST['form_botcheck'];

        $toemail = 'zigasetar@gmail.com'; // Your Email Address
        $toname = 'ThemeMascot'; // Your Name

        if( $botcheck == '' ) {

            $mail->SetFrom( $toemail , $toname );
            $mail->AddReplyTo( $email , $name );
            $mail->AddAddress( $toemail , $toname );
            $mail->Subject = $subject;

            $name = isset($name) ? "Name: $name<br><br>" : '';
            $email = isset($email) ? "Email: $email<br><br>" : '';
            $phone = isset($phone) ? "Phone: $phone<br><br>" : '';
            $message = isset($message) ? "Message: $message<br><br>" : '';

            $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ? '<br><br><br>This Form was submitted from: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '';

            $body = "$name $email $phone $message $referrer";

            $mail->MsgHTML( $body );
            $sendEmail = $mail->Send();
            echo $sendEmail;

            if( $sendEmail == true ):
                $message = 'We have <strong>successfully</strong> received your Message and will get Back to you as soon as possible.';
                $status = "true";
            else:
                $message = 'Email <strong>could not</strong> be sent due to some Unexpected Error. Please Try Again later.<br /><br /><strong>Reason:</strong><br />' . $mail->ErrorInfo . '';
                $status = "false";
            endif;
        } else {
            $message = 'Bot <strong>Detected</strong>.! Clean yourself Botster.!';
            $status = "false";
        }
    } else {
        $message = 'Please <strong>Fill up</strong> all the Fields and Try Again.';
        $status = "false";
    }
} else {
    $message = 'An <strong>unexpected error</strong> occured. Please Try Again later.';
    $status = "false";
}

$status_array = array( 'message' => $message, 'status' => $status);
echo json_encode($status_array);
?>
```

I have the right password, and those credentials are bassicly copy-paste from Mailtrap's SMTP settings. When I exectue the script via form in my index.html web page, the request allways just times out.

*2023-07-31 21:55:19 Connection: opening to ssl://sandbox.smtp.mailtrap.io:25, timeout=300, options=array ( ) 2023-07-31 22:00:21 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Operation timed out (60) 2023-07-31 22:00:21 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting {"message":"Email could not</strong> be sent due to some Unexpected Error. Please Try Again later.
Reason:</strong>
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting","status":"false"}*

I also have port 25 enabled in the php.ini, so this shouldn't be problem. I also have the class.smtp.php and class.pop3.php in the given path located.

I don't know what else to do.. DO you have any ideas for debugging this?

I am testing it locally from my MacBook

Thanks

---

**It is working now, what I did is:**
Would you change anything?

```
$mail->isSMTP();    
$mail->Host = 'sandbox.smtp.mailtrap.io'; 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;          
$mail->Username = 'e58e3babe7d651'; 
$mail->Password = '9b******345c';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; 
$mail->Port = 587;
```

Comment: I think for a secure connection you use port 587, not 25?

Comment: You can't do explicit SSL on port 25. See [the docs](https://mailtrap.io/blog/starttls-ssl-tls/).

Comment: What Alex said, and it won't help that you're using a very old version of PHPMailer that's no longer supported (as you would know if you had followed the link in the error message). [Get the latest version](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). The same docs also tell you [which flavours of encryption work on which ports](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#using-encryption), so I suggest you read that.

Comment: I managed it to work, so I updated my question. It is working on port 587 and tls encryption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error "Failed to connect to server: Operation timed out (60)" indicates that you can not get a connection to the server "sandbox.smtp.mailtrap.io" on port 25. I have checked and I can connect to port 25 of that server from my end using telnet:
[image: Using telnet sandbox.smtp.mailtrap.io 25 to check connection to sandbox.smtp.mailtrap.io on port 25]

So what's most likely happening is your Internet provider or your hosting provider is blocking connections on port 25. This is done frequently to block spam and if you're paying for the hosting you can usually contact the hosting support to get it unblocked.

However an easier option might be to try different ports.

MailTrap is offering ports 25, 465, 587 and 2525: https://help.mailtrap.io/article/5-smtp-integration

You can try changing this part of your code with the corresponding ports:

```
$mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to
```

Mailtrap documentation seems to say that all ports support SSL, but it's uncommon to have it on port 25. And port 2525 seems to be like an alternative  version of port 25, there is a chance that it is not going to support the non-SSL connection.

If you use port 2525 and get an SSL error you might try changing this line as well:

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'none';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
```

If you use port 2525 and get an SSL error you might try changing this line as well:

Also consider trying tls encryption:

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
```

However I would advise to try to get it working on port 465 with SSL on as then your emails will be encrypted.

Comment: I managed it to work, so I updated my question. It is working on port 587 and tls encryption.

Comment: @devZ I think TLS encryption is being phased out, but as long as it's working for you now, you should be all set for the foreseeable future unless mailtrap decides to change something. If this answered your question, please accept the answer.  I edited the answer to include tls.